# Showing that $a \sin x \pm b \cos y =\sqrt{q^2+r^2}\;\sin\left(\frac{x\pm y}{2}+\arctan\frac{r}{q}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble showing this formula, can you give me a hand?
$$a \sin x \pm b \cos y =\sqrt{q^2+r^2}\;\sin\left(\frac{x\pm y}{2}+\arctan\frac{r}{q}\right)$$
where
$$q=(a+b)\cos\frac{x\mp y}{2}$$
$$r=(a-b)\sin\frac{x\mp y}{2}$$
This is the point where I arrived,by extending the right side
$$a \left[\cos\frac{x∓y}{2}\sin\frac{x±y}{2}+\sin\frac{x∓y}{2}\cos\frac{x±y}{2} \right]+$$ $$b\left[\cos\frac{x\mp y}{2}\sin\frac{x±y}{2}-\sin\frac{x∓y}{2}\cos\frac{x±y}{2} \right]$$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the right-hand side?

Comment: @Blue yes, of course, but I don't find anything.

Comment: How far did you get? Generally, it's appreciated (if not expected) for you to include the work you've done and/or to explain exactly where you got stuck. This allows answerers to tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time telling you what you already know. You write that "of course" you tried expanding the right-hand side, even though your question makes no mention of this. I wouldn't want to expend a lot of effort explaining an approach only to have you respond (as sometimes happens here) "*Of course*, I already tried that. I was looking for something better."

Comment: @Blue sorry for that, I have edited the question.

Comment: You are *very* close! (It's a good thing I didn't bother writing-out a solution. ;) Notice, for, instance, that $a$ is multiplied by an expression of the form $$\sin \alpha \cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta$$ (except that the pieces are in a different order, which is okay). I suspect you know a way to simplify that.

Comment: @Blue So it becomes $a\ sin x$, 
how can I prove that the other expression is equal to $b \cos y$?

Comment: Note that the formula is correct for all values of the variables only if the arctangent is understood as $\arctan(x, y)$ (the principal value of $\arg(x +i y)$).